# Changing underline style Link

Tags: css, material-ui

I would like to change the underline style while hovering. To be more specific what I am trying to do is to change the color and the size of the underlined link.

```
  const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    button: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(2),
   },
  }));

 <MaterialLink
    component="button"
    aria-owns={anchorEl ? 'mouse-over-popover' : undefined}
    onMouseEnter={handlePopperOpen}
    onClick={handlePopperOpen}
    color="inherit"
 >
      <Typography variant="subtitle1" color="inherit" >Buisness Services</Typography>
 </MaterialLink>
```

Could anyone guide me on how can I customize the underline while hovering?

Example:[image]

Comment: To clarify a bit more, you want to change only the underline? Not the fontSize or color of the whole link while hovering?

Comment: Yes that correct

Comment: const theme = createMuiTheme({
        overrides: {
            MuiLink: {
                underlineHover: {
                    "&:hover": {
                        color: 'red',
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    }); This is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for:

```
 const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiLink: {
            button: {
                "&:hover": {
                    borderBottom: '2px solid #3F51B5'
                }
            },
        }
    }
});
```